# angle of segment opposite

Tags: python

Using a script to make a circle segment I run into this "Issue"

The default value of the angle is 120.
When running the script it draws vertices starting at the left side.
See screenshot

[image: 120 degrees]

As you can see the angle is 120 degrees (this should be zero (0)

See next screenshot

[image: zero degrees]

The degrees is now 0 and the segment is drawn.

Off course this should be the opposite. (0 is not drawn and 120 if drawn)

What do I need to change in the angle_end var to flip the angle?
Default value is 120. When running the script it should draw the segment and not 1 vertice.

Code snippet attached below

```
h = self.height
diam1 = abs(self.diam)
r = diam1/2
selfangle = abs(self.angle)
 

    # Circle partially above x-axis
    angle_start = math.pi - math.asin(h/r) ##math.pi - math.asin(h/r)
    **angle_end = (math.pi - angle_start + math.radians(self.angle))** 




for i in range(self.segments+1):
    factor = i / self.segments
    angle = angle_start*(1 - factor) + angle_end*factor
    verts.append((math.cos(angle)*r, math.sin(angle)*r - h, 0.0))
```

Comment: do you have full code?

Comment: I will add the code later and edit the post